# Convergence of residual and error of linear first-order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a rather simple problem in a broader context that I think holds true but which I fail to prove.

Let $h$ be a polynomial function. Consider the linear ODE $u' - u h' = 0$. As far as I know the only possible solutions are of the form $u(x) = c\,\exp h(x)$ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ (depending on here unspecified initial conditions). Assume that $u\in H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)$, where $\rho$ is the Gaussian measure. I want to show that if the residual of the ODE converges to zero, that $u$ has to converge to an exponential, i.e.

$$
\Vert u'-u\,h'\Vert_{L^2(\mathbb{R},\rho)} \to 0
\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad
\min_{c\in\mathbb{R}}\Vert c\,\exp h - u\Vert_{H^1(\mathbb{R},\rho)} \to 0.
$$

My gut says this should be true, but so far I failed at a formal proof. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.
On the other hand, any notes on why this is wrong (if this is the case) are helpful, too.